# how to concatenate the grep output and the indexed string in bash?

Tags: bash

I am running a `for loop` such like

```
for d in /dir1/dir2/*.txt:
do
    cat $d | grep "^ABC" >output.txt 
done
```

My question is how to concatenate both `$d` and the output for `grep`? such like

```
/dir1/dir2/demp1.txt ABCDEFG
/dir1/dir2/demp2.txt ABCD
...
```

Comment: Remove the `cat` and just `grep -H '^ABC' "$d" >> output.txt`

Comment: cat is just an example. it's actually a program though.

Comment: Your for-loop doesn't make sense; there are both syntax errors and "that can't possibly be what he wants to do" errors. It's great that you're simplifying your example to post it -- more people should do that -- but you do need to make sure that the simplified example actually works and does what it's intended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop store the output of the command in a variable:

```
   e=$(cat ${d} | grep "^ABC")
   echo -e "$d\t$e" >> output.txt
```